# How to debug your tests when using testinfra as verifier in Molecule

Tags: ansible, pytest, molecule, testinfra

When testing an ansible role using molecule tool and verifying the result with testinfra(pytest), I am not able to print or debug certain output or an ansible variable.

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.5, pytest-4.6.6, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0 -- /root/test1/myenv/bin/python2
using: pytest-4.6.6 pylib-1.8.0
setuptools registered plugins:
  testinfra-3.2.1 at /root/test1/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/testinfra/plugin.py
rootdir: /root/test1/server_manager/molecule/default
plugins: testinfra-3.2.1
collected 1 item

tests/test_default.py::test_Ansible_variable[ansible://instance] PASSED  [100%]

=========================== 1 passed in 3.29 seconds ===========================
```

Is there is a way to do that?

Comment: Did you try to pass the `--debug` option to molecule command. This is supposed to append the  `-vvv` flag to pytest and increase the test verbosity.

Comment: I am using it already but nothing is showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the testinfra verifier component in `molecule.yml` file, enable the 's' option. For example:

```
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: docker
lint:
  name: yamllint
platforms:
  - name: instance
    image: centos:7
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  lint:
    name: ansible-lint
verifier:
  name: testinfra
  lint:
    name: flake8
  options:
    s: true
```